# Creating a Method in C#

Tags: c#, methods

I'm in the process of creating my first method. So far it looks pretty good. However, there is a mistake.

My Method:

```
public string ConvertNameToID(string name)
        {
            var filename = "./XML/sus.xml";
            var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var susFilepath = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, filename);

            XElement xelement = XElement.Load(susFilepath);
            IEnumerable<XElement> msus = xelement.Elements();

            var SuSid = from sus in msus
                        where sus.Element("NAME").Value == name
                        select sus;

            foreach (var sus in SuSid)
            {
               SuSID = sus.Element("ID").Value;
            }
            return SuSID;
        }
```

And the error is:

```
The name 'SuSID' does not exist in the current context
```

Comment: c# is case sensitive, and foreach loop is a non sese. probaby you wont .. return SuSid.First(p=>p.Element("ID").Value)

Answer (score 1):

Typo: "SuSid" is your variable

Edit: Sorry that was wrong. You did not declare SuSID before: `(Type) SuSID = null` for example `string SuSID = null` if it is a string.

Comment: Perfect, that's the solution!

Comment: @Sascha If so, then consider marking this answer with the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

SuSID is equal to SuSid? If C# is case sensitive, it probably understands that SuSID is different from SuSid. Try to change this and see if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var sus in SuSid)
{
    // In order to use `SuSID` which is distinct from `SuSid`, 
    // you need to declare it first.
    SuSID = sus.Element("ID").Value;
}
return SuSID; // To return `SuSID` here, it must be accessible in this context
              // which means: you need to declare it outside of `foreach`.
```

So, to make this "work" you'd need to do

```
string SuSID = null;
foreach ...
```

---

But does this make sense? - I think not, because all you'll ever return is the **last value** from the foreach iterations!

If this is what you actually want, you could just do

```
return msus.LastOrDefault(sus => sus.Element("NAME").Value == name)?.Element("ID")?.Value; 
// add `?? ""` maybe,  if you want to return "" as "not found";
```

See: [Enumerable.LastOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault?view=net-5.0)